# `adm-zip` compression issue

Tags: node.js, adm-zip

I am using [adm-zip](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip) to create a `zip file` in NodeJS successfully.

The issue comes when extracting manually (as end user will do) as there appears to be a compression issue on a video file.

A suggested fix might be to set `adm-zip` to use STORE instead of COMPRESS, though the documentation is lacking in how to do this.

Anyone know?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get errors from the decompression software?

Comment: correct. across 3 different OS's

Comment: So what exactly are the errors?